# Can I install a package offline using npm while I have installed it globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

So, sometimes I can't use the Internet, but I have installed those packages I need globally. Can I install a package locally when I'm offline? Because, I think I have already installed it, why must I download those files again?

I have tried npm-cache, but that's not what I want.

Comment: You can copy from globally to project folder.

Comment: Thats a feasible way, but it is inconvenient to configure my project after I copy those files.